# Add vb.net forms to c# project

Tags: c#, vb.net, visual-studio

In vb.net, the `Login Form`, `Splash Screen`, and `Dialog Form` are nice to have.  They are available through Visual Studio's `Project` > `Add New Item...` dialog.

Is there a way to add these prebuilt forms to a c# project without jumping through hoops?

If need be, the forms can be re-implemented or created in a vb.net project and then instantiated from the main (c#) project, but that is a lot of work if there's an easy workaround.

---

**vb.net project**

[image]

---

**c# project**

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think using VB.NET forms in C# is not *directly* possible. But you could put a wrapper around the VB.NET forms and compile it into a DLL. Then you can use the DLL from your C# application. A similar suggestion (but the other way round) is given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/862723/use-vb-net-and-c-sharp-in-the-same-application).

**Edit:** Actually you don't need a wrapper. You can use the form from the project directly as shown [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/csharpgeneral/thread/3118937a-c908-471b-ac3c-8a20e7cab718).

Comment: This is what I've done to get around the issue in the past.  I was hoping that I had missed something simple and there was a c# version of the forms "hidden" somewhere.

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by a "wrapper"? If the forms were in a separate project, why do you think that the C# project couldn't just use `new VBForm()`?

Comment: @John: Sorry, made a mistake. I made an edit for clarification.

Answer (score 2):

You can create your own C# versions of the VB templates by (manually) converting the .zip files in C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE\ItemTemplates\VisualBasic\Windows Forms\1033.

1. Copy and unzip the required template
2. Manually convert the VB code to C# code
3. Modify, and save the .vstemplate XML file (see also the [schema](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xwkxbww4.aspx) reference)
4. Compress the files into a new .zip
5. Drop the C# .zip inside C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE\ItemTemplates\CSharp\Windows Forms\1033

Comment: Can you elaborate on the steps required?

Comment: Well there's a lot to it (see my edits and http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms185319.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't combine multiple languages in one project. Simply create a separate project for your VB.NET forms library.

Comment: I know that I can't combine languages in a single project, I was just wondering if there was a similar c# implementation of the vb.net forms (just like you can create a user form in either c# or vb.net).

Comment: If there were a similar implementation (from Microsoft) then you would see it in the Add New Item dialog.

Comment: look into adding to the using , using Microsoft.VisualBasic I've done this in the past.. just code it in C# LOL

Answer (score 0):

you cannot mix VB and C# in the same `project` but you can combine/group a C# project and a VB.NET project into the same VS `solution`.

in this case you could have a class library written in `vb.net` which hosts your special forms and a `windows application` written in `C#` which references the other one and uses those forms, provided you make those public.

Answer (score 0):

Only thing I can think of is to make the primary project of your application a VB project. That's the only thing that'll allow you to use the `My.Application.SplashScreen` property, and you'll only be able to use it from within the VB parts of your app (trying to use `Application.SplashScreen` from within C# will not compile).

Comment: I've used splash screens in c# before doing more or less what is suggested here: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winforms/thread/8af9fd3e-f679-40b4-976a-46f42319e9a5/