# How can i add vb.net dll into c# application

Tags: c#, vb.net, dll, ilmerge

I have develop one application in C# windows in this i need to add vb.net dll files.I have try add dll files from source->add References.But,i am getting error

```
   **Could not find the dll files **
```

Because i am adding the dll files (**assembly1 into assembly**2 and **assembly2 into assembly3** )

** New Code **

C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft\ILMerge>ilmerge /t:dll /out:ExcelImportnew.dll ExcelImport.dll BOL.dll

An exception occurred during merging:

```
      Access to the path 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft\ILMerge\ExcelImportnew.dll' is denied.
       at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath)
          at System.IO.FileStream.Init(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, Int32 rights, Boolea
         useRights, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options, SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES secAttrs, Sring msgPath, Boolean bFromProxy)
               at System.IO.FileStream..ctor(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share, In32 bufferSize, FileOptions options, String msgPath, Boolean bFromProxy)
            at System.IO.FileStream..ctor(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share)
            at System.Compiler.Writer.WritePE(String location, Boolean writeDebugSymbols, Module module, Boolean delaySign, String keyFileName, String keyName)
             at System.Compiler.Writer.WritePE(CompilerParameters compilerParameters, Module module)
           at ILMerging.ILMerge.Merge()
            at ILMerging.ILMerge.Main(String[] args)
```

Please tell me why i am getting this error.How can i resolve this error. 
Thanks !

Comment: Add references to all those assemblies (1, 2 and then 3)

Comment: Each project compiles as a separate DLL, so you will need to add references to both of the other dlls.

Comment: Hi thank you for your reply .Is it mean to add that asb1 and asm2 to into asm3.Actually assembly3 is my main dll file.

Comment: Hi SSS i have compile each project and i added dll files into my main project that is assembly3,but it doesn't find the file path.I have set properties copy to local too.

Comment: check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/862723/use-vb-net-and-c-sharp-in-the-same-application

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried to combine the dll's with ILMerge?

```
ilmerge /target:library /out:YourLib.dll ClassLibrary1.dll ClassLibrary2.dll
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have the source code to both the VB and the C# project, add both of them to a Visual Studio solution. Now you can add them as Project References.

This may be the easiest way to get started.