# Map Properties Of a class to an interface

Tags: c#, inheritance, interface, attributes

I'm just wondering if there is a way to Map Properties from a class to an interface with out changing their names.

Say you imported some entities from a Database

```
public partial class Post
{
    public int PostId {get; set;}
}

public partial  class Book
{
    public int BookId {get; set;}
}
```

and an interface:

```
public interface IHasID
{
   int Id {get; set;}
}
```

is there a way to inherit from this interface and just map the Properties using attributes like:

```
public partial class Post : IHasID
{
    [MetadataTypeAttribute(typeof(IHasID.Id))]
    public int PostId;
}
```

I just want a simple way to do this without wrapping all of the code or changing the database.  Is there a way to wrap the parital class to point its property as an interface property?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could create an `ID` property which gets and sets your object's appropriate ID, like this:

```
public partial class Post : IHasID
{
    [NotMapped]
    public int Id 
    {
        get { return PostId; }
        set { PostId = value; }
    }

    public int PostId { get; set; }

    ...
```

You would of course do the same thing for `Book`.

Comment: This works thanks, I'll mark it as the answer when the alloted time is up

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if it's worth pointing out just for the sake of knowledge that, if it were vb.net, you could do it just like this:

```
Partial Public Class Post
    Implements IHasID

    Public Property PostId As Integer Implements IHasID.Id
End Class
```

Comment: It would be.  I love C# and use it almost exclusively now, but I started off my career in VB.NET, and I see a lot of unwarranted VB.NET hate coming from C# lovers.  In fact, there are plenty of places, like this, where VB.NET is ahead of C#.

Comment: Not everybody knows every language. Usually tags gives hint of which language is preferred. VB answer is good if author is willing to use it or is prepared for [some tricks](http://stackoverflow.com/q/862723/1997232). Which may not be the case. Which you can clarify in comments first. I wouldn't be happy to get vb.net (or tbh any in other than `C#` language) answer in one of my `C#` questions.

Comment: @Sinatr -- That's a good point, but on the other hand, questions don't belong to the authors, they belong to the community.  If you do a google search for the question's title, you might be looking for vb.  I don't think it's really offensive, necessarily, to have a vb-related response to a question tagged with c#, especially given that it's drawing a comparison to C#.  I weighed the choice, and I thought that it's better to spread potentially-useful information than to worry that someone might get offended that there's an answer they don't consider too relevant.

Comment: I disagree with you. It's totally fine to ask same exactly question but for different languages. We have plenty of *similar* questions for `C#` and `C++` and they shouldn't be mixed into one ever. Even same language but different technologies (e.q. `winforms` and `wpf`) should be split.

Comment: That's fine.  You can disagree.  In fact, I feel that our disagreement, played out here in the comments, is basically meta-information that serves to even better the usefulness of the discussion.  It's improving the information on the web.  You're teaching people that it might not be a good idea to do what I've done.